# Importing scss file won't auto generate css, shows compilation error in output

Tags: css, import, sass, compilation

As an exercise for our course we are to import an scss file into another to auto generate a compiled css file for our html.

However when i input the following: `@import "_nest.scss" ;`
It does not seem to generate the css file, because of a compilation error.

The following error occurs in my output tab:

```
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "�": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "��@"
    on line 1 of sass/c:\Users\Manten\Desktop\becode\Exercises\sass-challenge\css\style.scss
>> ��@
   ^
```

I cannot seem to fix the error, however I try. I've included images of my folder structure, css link in html and what is inside of the SCSS files.
The most common error I occured online was naming the files .sass instead of .scss but that isn't the case for me.

Thanks in advance!
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6pfD.png)

[Html stylesheet link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxKmK.png)

[Import code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glZjI.png)

[first scss line of code in _nest.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WPKe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must exclude the '_' and the '.scss' extension. Also, start your path with './nest';
So your final code will look like this

```
@import './nest';
```

Comment: I've changed my code to @import "./nest"; sadly no change and still the same compilation error after saving and refreshing

Comment: I deleted all my scss files, remade them and retyped the code (although i had already done this and it didn't help). Now when tried typing the @import "./nest" path it automatically completed it. When typed it out myself, it did not work.. Odd, but fixed
Thanks!

Comment: I have done so. Accounts under 15rep dont show upvotes visibly